Trying to update the value of the datetime_picker via JS using Backpack for Laravel
I have added a couple of datetime_picker fields in my CRUD Controller's setupCreateOperation function and I am trying to use a JS file to set a value for one of the fields based on the selection of the other.
So for example, if you select a timestamp from the first field, the second will auto-populate with a value of the same date + 1hr.
When I set the field the value gets updated in the hidden element, but the UI does not update. I tried using .change() to force the field to update, but it does not seem to work.
Here is the code in the CRUD Controller for the fields:
        CRUD::addField([
            'name'  => 'listing_appointment_date',
            'label' => 'Listing Appointment Date',
            'type'  => 'datetime_picker',
            'wrapper'         => [ 
                'class'      => 'form-group col-md-6'
            ], 
        ],);

        CRUD::addField([
            'name'  => 'video_post_date',
            'label' => 'Send Date',
            'type'  => 'datetime_picker',
            'wrapper'         => [ 
                'class'      => 'form-group col-md-6'
            ], 
        ],);

and the code in my JS file:
crud.field('listing_appointment_date').onChange(function(field) {
     if (field.value){
          if (!crud.field('video_post_date').value) {
               var date = new Date(field.value);
               var newTime = date.setTime(date.getTime() + 3600000);
               var newDate = new Date(newTime);
               var year = newDate.getFullYear();
               var month = String(newDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
               var day = String(newDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
               var hours = String(newDate.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
               var minutes = String(newDate.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
               var seconds = String(newDate.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
               var formattedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
               crud.field('video_post_date').input.value = formattedDate;
               crud.field('video_post_date').change();
          }       
     }
}).change();

I can see in the HTML element that the value is being updated:
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="video_post_date" value="2024-07-18 19:04:14">

...but it is not showing in the UI.
Any help would be much appreciated :)
